# React Native - No such file or directory, open 'app\build\intermediates\merged_manifests\debug\AndroidManifest.xml'

Tags: npm, react-native, node-modules, react-native-ios

I am using **React Native 0.61.5**, after installing **@react-native-community/cli** and running **react-native run-android** this issue appeared:

```
info Running jetifier to migrate libraries to AndroidX. You can disable it using "--no-jetifier" flag.
Jetifier found 864 file(s) to forward-jetify. Using 4 workers...
info Starting JS server...
error ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'app\build\intermediates\merged_manifests\debug\AndroidManifest.xml'. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'app\build\intermediates\merged_manifests\debug\AndroidManifest.xml'
    at Object.openSync (fs.js:440:3)
    at Object.readFileSync (fs.js:342:35)
    at getLaunchPackageName (C:\Users\Gabriel\Desktop\testeProjeto\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\getLaunchPackageName.js:161:33)
    at buildAndRun (C:\Users\Gabriel\Desktop\testeProjeto\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\index.js:163:63)
    at C:\Users\Gabriel\Desktop\testeProjeto\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\index.js:135:12
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:94:5)
    at async Command.handleAction (C:\Users\Gabriel\Desktop\testeProjeto\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\index.js:182:9)
```

Comment: facing same issue

Comment: deleting build folder inside android/app/ used to be just fine, now it is causing an error, any solution to this?

Comment: In my case, there is no `build` folder and I get this error

Comment: Does this answer your question? [No such file or directory, open 'app\build\intermediates\merged\_manifests\debug\AndroidManifest.xml' in React-Native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60218063/no-such-file-or-directory-open-app-build-intermediates-merged-manifests-debug)

Answer (score 0):

As this [answer says](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60218742/9119186):

> There seems to be an issue with the latest version of @react-native-community/cli-platform-android 3.1.1.
>
> I have resolved my issue by downgrading to an older version of the library by adding this to my package.json.
>
> ```
> "resolutions": {
>     "@react-native-community/cli-platform-android": "2.9.0"
> }
> ```
>
> After that, remove the node_modules folder and run `yarn` or `npm install` again.